# How to ensure centering of middle column with CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have three columns; a main column in the middle, and two to each side. The widths of the two side columns changes according to their content - one of them might even be empty. I want the content of the middle column to be able to grow, while maintaining the width of the two side columns.

**Here's a snippet with my attempt:**

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  gap: 16px;
}

.row > * {
  background-color: #ccccff;
  height: 40px;
}
.middle {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="right">Hello</div>
  <div class="middle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
  <div class="left">X</div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve, is for the "Hello" and "X" column to have same width, without manually having to specify a constant minimum width (using something like `minmax(100px, 1fr)`), such that whatever content is in the middle, it is always centered on the screen. The above snippet works fine when the content in the middle column is somewhat short, but I want the two side columns to maintain their width, even as the middle column grows. Is there a way to do this using CSS Grid, Flexbox or some other means? (besides JavaScript)

Comment: You want the first and last column to influence each other as in be the width of the widest one, while the middle one take all available space, Is this right ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yes, exactly. Well put.

Comment: CSS only solution is not possible, There is no way for columns to influence each other, One potential solution would be `flex:1 0 0;` on outer columns, this way they will always have the same width because they stretch to consume the space evenly, which leaves us you with the middle column causing all sorts of problems, either we give it a higher flex-grow value, or the same as the  outer columns with a scrollbar or ..., Stretching  the outer columns isn't a viable solution as it, we merely want the columns to be as wide as the widest which is not possible as mentioned before.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I was afraid there wasn't an easy solution. I spend quite a while trying to figure it out yesterday, so I were mostly hoping I was just missing something. I'll probably go with `minmax(some-constant, 1fr)` for the outer columns. It'll have to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with minmax for example:

```css
grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 40px) auto minmax(0, 40px);
```

Change the pixels as you need.
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax()) is the reference in case you need more information.

Comment: The issues is, that I cannot set the pixels to a fixed constant, since I do not necessarily know the width of the content of the outer most columns.

Answer (score 0):

Complementary to [vitomadio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68818062/11041841), If we have like 3 columns, we can set the width of the other columns to `1fr`, and set the middle one as `auto`.

```css
grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
```

Comment: If you look at the question, that's exactly what I initially attempted, unfortunately without much success.